# Subscribe works & complete doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material, rxjs6

After loading the data through an http call to the server, I want to use the complete part of the subscription to open the material-sidenav. I have double checked and know that the subscribe part loads the data, but the complete section doesn't get called at all.
Here is the code:

```
this.bs.getAddons().subscribe((data: any) => {//Done Loading packages -> load addons
      this.bs.addons = data,
      error => console.log(error),
      () => sidenav.open();
    });
```

Comment: Remove the curly braces

Comment: That Sebastian, didn't know it was that simple.